Java Mockito: MockedStatic in own line, without curly braces
Is there any way to move code out the MockedStatic curly brackets and make everything its own line, without side effects? Just curious looking at the template here, If there is no answer, thats fine. We have multiple MockedStatic, and its causing 2-3 layer curly brackets.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62860455/15435022
assertEquals("foo", Foo.method());
try (MockedStatic mocked = mockStatic(Foo.class)) {
 mocked.when(Foo::method).thenReturn("bar");
 assertEquals("bar", Foo.method());
 mocked.verify(Foo::method);
}
assertEquals("foo", Foo.method());

"In your case, something like this:"
  @Test
  public void testStaticMockWithVerification() throws SQLException {
    try (MockedStatic<DriverManager> dummy = Mockito.mockStatic(DriverManager.class)) {
      DatabaseConnectionFactory factory = new MySQLDatabaseConnectionFactory();
      dummy.when(() -> DriverManager.getConnection("arg1", "arg2", "arg3"))
        .thenReturn(new Connection() {/*...*/});

      factory.getConnection();

      dummy.verify(() -> DriverManager.getConnection(eq("arg1"), eq("arg2"), eq("arg3")));
    }
  }


If you just want to avoid deep nesting, you can put multiple "resources" (in this case, mockStatic calls) in a single try-with-resources statement.
try (MockedStatic<Foo> mocked1 = mockStatic(Foo.class);
     MockedStatic<Bar> mocked2 = mockStatic(Bar.class);
     MockedStatic<Baz> mocked3 = mockStatic(Baz.class)) {
    // do your tests here...
}

If you really want to remove all the curly braces, you can always just manually call close() yourself, but this is more error-prone, as you might forget to that.
MockedStatic<Foo> mocked1 = mockStatic(Foo.class);
MockedStatic<Bar> mocked2 = mockStatic(Bar.class);
MockedStatic<Baz> mocked3 = mockStatic(Baz.class);

// do your tests here...

mocked3.close();
mocked2.close();
mocked1.close();


why is my question downvoted btw? just trying to learn, (it prob wasn't you)  feel free to upvote it, thanks ! gave points and accepted answer
